# ¿Por qué un "hijo habido en buena guerra" es un hijo habido fuera del matrimonio y no al revés?

Tags: etimología, modismos, parentesco

En la entrada [hijo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KOGiy39) del DLE encuentro (negritas mías):

> **hijo, ja habido, da, en buena guerra**
>   1. m. y f. hijo habido **fuera del matrimonio**.

por otro lado, en la entrada [**guerra**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JoNxOnS) se recoge (negritas mías):

> **en buena guerra**
>   1. loc. adv. Luchando **con lealtad**.

¿No debería ser al reves, es decir, el nacido dentro del matrimonio?

Comment: Puede que se refiera a lealtad a la amante. A fin de cuentas, buena o mala ha sido un hijo nacido en guerra, y no en paz.

Comment: Para mí más que destacar lealtad a el/la amante, en lugar del cónyuge, creo que la expresión rebosa ironía

Answer (score 5):

> *Yerros de amor, eslabonados por su difunto padre el Rey don Alonso en diferentes hijos habidos en buena guerra, dejaron á este príncipe desgraciado preparada la cadena de desdichas; [...].*
>
> Bartolomé José Gallardo, "Artículos literarios", 1832 (España).

Este es el único caso claro que encuentro en el CORDE de la expresión. Sin embargo, se venía usando desde bastante antes. En el *Diccionario de autoridades* se describe así:

> Hijo habido en buena *guerra*, por antiphrasis. Se llama el habido fuera del matrimonio.

Así pues, queda claro que el origen es irónico, como la propia definición de *antiphrasis* nos indica:

> ANTIPHRASIS. s. f. Figúra irónica, por la qual diciendo una cosa se quiere dár à entender su totalmente contrária: como llamar pelón al que no tiene pelo.

Me resulta muy curiosa la construcción, porque el propio *Diccionario de autoridades* describe *guerra* como:

> GUERRA. Se llaman tambien las dissensiones entre personas, y especialmente entre los domésticos: como entre Marido y muger, parientes y criados, que riñen mucho sin tener quietúd.

Por tanto, se puede entender la expresión como "un hijo habido durante un periodo de guerra doméstica", aunque la guerra no haya sido precisamente "buena":

> Buena *guerra*. Se dice de la pressa, ù otra accion militar, executada conforme à las leyes y usos recibidos y admitidos generalmente.

No me parece a mí que por entonces se admitiera mucho el tener hijos fuera del matrimonio (salvo si eras un rey u otra persona igual de rica y poderosa, claro).

Answer (score 0):

Soy traductora y pienso que a todos ustedes les falta la picardía latinoamericana (o más bien chilena, quizás),  "Ir a la guerra" en Chile significa una persona que va muy arreglada para ir a encontrarse con alguien y tener relaciones sexuales fuera del matrimonio, o como sea.  Por tanto, y con picardía, podemos interpretar que la buena guerra fue un encuentro "muy entretenido" de cual resultó un hijo.

La mayoría de los dichos populares son picarescos.  No se saca nada con interpretarlos según el diccionario.